# Dependency injected HttpClient runs locally but service not found in Azure

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have the following in `Startup.cs` in a function:

```cs
services
    .AddTransient<AuthenticationDelegationHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationDelegationHandler>();
```

And in a trigger I inject this:

```cs
private readonly IMyService _service;
private readonly ILogger<HttpTrigger> _logger;

public HttpTrigger(IMyService service, ILogger<HttpTrigger> logger)
{
    _service = service;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

When I run this locally, everything works fine. When I deploy to Azure, it fails saying it can't find any `IMyService` to inject.

A [closer inspection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions-addhttpclient-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection)) of `.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>` reveals:

> The client name will be set to the type name of TClient

So when I change to just `MyService` in my injected constructor, it works neither locally nor in Azure.

Finally, I changed my DI wiring to:

```cs
services
    .AddTransient<AuthenticationDelegationHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient<MyService>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationDelegationHandler>();
```

And my trigger to:

```cs
private readonly IMyService _service;
private readonly ILogger<HttpTrigger> _logger;

public HttpTrigger(MyService service, ILogger<HttpTrigger> logger)
{
    _service = service;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

This works locally, but again not in Azure.

Each time I call the function in Azure, I see variations of the following:

```
Executed 'HttpTrigger' (Failed, Id=7aa3d31b-e98c-4034-9770-8e7a283382a5, Duration=0ms)System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'Services.MyService' while attempting to activate 'Function.HttpTrigger'.
```

What am I doing wrong here, as everything is working flawlessly locally? How can I make Azure happy with my depedency injection configuration?

Comment: There may be a difference between what runs in the emulator (I think this runs directly from your project's 'bin' folders) and what is published to Azure. Try publishing to folder and run it locally in the Azure Functions docker image, and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yesterday I tried for some time to get the docker runtime to work. It picks up my endpoint and logs its methods but crashes immediately afterwards with `A host error has occurred during startup operation 'e8fe5664-d6a8-4898-b195-085cd50bc03c'. - System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is very much my own fault. When I deployed to Azure I used:

```bash
dotnet publish Function.csproj --configuration Release --output ./output
```

Running the project locally with the `Release` profile produces the same error.